# Примеры в правиле о приложении (Розенталь)

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

У Розенталя (*Примечание. Второе тире опускается*):

3) если приложение предшествует определяемому слову:
Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны — спортсмены клуба «Фили» (Москва) одержали третью победу подряд.
Глашатай лесов — кукушка известила всех о событии.

Непонятно, где это опущенное тире могло бы стоять? Ведь приложение находится в начале предложения.

Например, если бы было:
Сегодня в Москве () один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны — спортсмены клуба «Фили» одержали третью победу подряд.
Или:
Вчера вечером () глашатай лесов — кукушка известила всех о событии.

Имелось ли в виду в правиле, что именно в таких случаях тире на месте скобок опускается?

По-моему, приведенные у Розенталя примеры не показательны, потому что приложение находится в начале предложения. И о каком втором тире идет тогда речь (второе тире как раз-таки на месте остается)? Может быть, надо говорить о первом тире?

Answer (score 3):

Если бы определяемое слово стояло первым, то указанные Вами предложения имели бы такой вид:

***Спортсмены*** клуба «Фили» (Москва) — один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны — **одержали** третью победу подряд.
**Кукушка** — глашатай лесов — **известила** всех о событии.

"Примечание. Второе тире опускается...[**(Розенталь, п.10.3)**](https://unotices.com/book.php?id=15800&page=17)" — **всё правильно**, опускается, действительно, второе тире (его место я отметила квадратными скобками):

Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны — спортсмены клуба «Фили» (Москва) [—]  одержали третью победу подряд.
Глашатай лесов — кукушка [—] известила всех о событии.

Если второе тире оставить, то "определяемость" смещается, возникает рассогласованность, несочетаемость:
*Один из аутсайдеров... одержали...

Глашатай... известила...*